How do you calculate a confidence interval if you only have an error for each input?
I have made a model (a python script), which takes as its input a scalar value $C_d$, and outputs a vector $\vec{u}$. I also know the 'real' output $\vec{u}^{\text{actual}}$ , which is calculated from measurement data. The goal of the model is to find the best estimate $\overline{C_d}$ of $C_d$, such that the output vector $\vec{u}$ for $\overline{C_d}$ is as close to $\vec{u}^{\text{actual}}$ as possible. I would like the model to generate a 95%-confidence interval for the $C_d$-estimate as well.
I defined an error $E=|| \vec{u}-\vec{u}^{\text{actual}}||$, which is a function of $C_d$. Naturally, the best estimate for $C_d$ would be to find the $C_d$ that results in the smallest error. Now as can be seen from the Error vs C_d graph, if the C_d changes from $\overline{C_d}$ to something else, the error quickly increases. This shows that we can be pretty sure that the actual $C_d$ is close to $\overline{C_d}$, meaning that the 95%-confidence interval for $C_d$ around $\overline{C_d}$ would not be very wide.

My question is now, how exactly can I calculate the bounds of this 95 % interval? There does not seem to be much information on the internet about calculating confidence intervals in the case only error is known, instead of a many data points $(C_d, \vec{u})$.
Thanks in advance
